# Gradle Kotlin : How to convert part of build.gradle script from groovy to build.gradle.kts syntaxe?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

Below a piece of groovy code :

```
compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions {
    moduleKind = "commonjs"
    outputFile = "node/crypto.js"
}
```

it gives the following error :

```
Script compilation errors:

  Line 44: compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions {
           ^ Unresolved reference: compileKotlin2Js

  Line 45:     moduleKind = "commonjs"
               ^ Unresolved reference: moduleKind

  Line 46:     outputFile = "node/crypto.js"
               ^ Unresolved reference: outputFile
```

How to translate it to kotlin syntaxe ?

Comment: Do you have a small example kts build that's failing and can be tested (with the plugins, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you're set up, but you should be able to add this to the top of your build script:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.Kotlin2JsCompile
```

Then do:

```
tasks.withType<Kotlin2JsCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions {
        moduleKind = "commonjs"
        outputFile = "node/crypto.js"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
tasks {
    "compileKotlin2Js"(Kotlin2JsCompile::class)  {
        kotlinOptions.metaInfo = true
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives ```Task with name 'compileKotlin2Js' not found in root project 'kotlin-minichain'```